# How to write file in server using header in php?

Tags: php, header

Actually I want to convert html into word(.doc). I am using the following  code to convert html to word

```
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.doc");
```

But This code is requesting force download in client system. How can i write the file in server as Word DoCument. Please Help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: The header does only give the client a hint of what it should do with the data, it does not perform any conversion.

Comment: There are libraries like PHPWord and phpdocx to do that job.

Comment: Can help me any other way to convert HTML to MS Word

Comment: PHPWord is probably the thing you should try out, just like @syck said.